# Mips, saving a character stored in a variable to register

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers, instructions

I've created a `.byte var1` in my `.data` segment. And now I want to store content of my var1 into $t1. To do that , should I use `lb` instructor or `la` instructor.To be honest I couldnt figure out the differences between two. Thanks in advance. Here is my try:

```
.data

var1: .byte '/'

.text

main:
   lb $t2,var1  #I want to t2 stores '/' character.
```

One more question: when I write `beq $t1,$t2`, does it compare two adresses, or the content of these two address?

Answer (score 3):

1. `lb` will load the 8 bit value from `var1` into `$t2`. `la` is a sudo-instruction that will load the full 32 bit address of the data in memory into `$t2` (assuming you are using 32-bit architecture). See [here](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html) for more details on MIPS instructions.
2. `Beq` compares the two values of `$t1` and `$t2`. If these are memory addresses, it will compare the addresses, not the data at those addresses.

Comment: thanks for reply. I've one more question. assume I did la `$s1 var1` . In this vay t1 stores the address of var1 right ? Then,I want to store same address into $t1 register so that I can change it without losing my start point of var1. To do that, `la $t1,0($s1)` is okey?

Comment: Yes that will work. Although, it may be more clear (at least, as clear as assembly can be) to write it as `la $t1 var1` if possible.